# Does the metric define a Riemannian Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Does a [Riemannian Manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold)'s [metric tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) $g$ completely define the manifold, or are more parameters required?

Comment: To assign the metric you must already have a manfold on which defining it! So in what sense could a metric define a manifold? Could you restate your question into a more explicit and clear manner?

Comment: I guess that answered my question. I was asking if the metric tensor of a manifold told you "everything you needed to know" about a manifold, or if there was more to the story.

Answer (score 4):

The metric tensor is the only *additional* thing you need to define a Riemannian manifold, beyond what you'd need in order to define the manifold as a differentiable manifold anyway even if it wasn't Riemannian. In particular, topology is important.  For example, just specifying that a 2-D manifold has a metric that's Euclidean everywhere is insufficient to define the manifold as being $R^2$ with a Euclidean metric, because another topological possibility for a 2-D manifold with a metric that's Euclidean everywhere is a cylinder.